# Phone icon with phone number on react Native page

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to put a phone icon along with phone number on my flat list. Right now, I am only displaying the phone number. My manager is asking me to put the phone icon along with when the user swipes the phone icon then the call can be placed I have the following code to display the phone number.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, FlatList, Text, View, Alert, TouchableOpacity, Linking } from 'react-native';
import ServiceDetails from '../reducers/ServiceDetails.json';

export default class ServiceListDetails extends Component {

  FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: .5,
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "#607D8B",
        }}
      />
    );
  }


_renderItem = ({item}) => {


 return(
            <View >
                <Text style={styles.Address1}>{item.addr} </Text>
                <Text style={styles.Address1}>{item.phone}</Text>
           </View>
           );
           }

componentDidCatch
render()
  {
   return(

     <View>
         <FlatList
          ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
    />


     </View>
  )
  }
  }
```

Right now, I can see

```
410 Test Drive
(912) 404-5555
_________________
213 Test drive1
(999) 222-1111
```

I want to put the phone icon and make it swipeable so that user can make the call from their phone.

any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what making the phone icon swipeable means. You can add an icon by using an icon library like this: https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/ or a font icon library.

Then you could use a library like this to execute the call: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-phone-call